# "Could not enter folder /media/sf_test": Trying to share folder between Kubuntu (guest) and Windows (host)

Tags: windows, virtualbox, shared-folders, kubuntu

I use VirtualBox 4.3.12 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate, and have a VM running  Kubuntu 14.10 Plasma 4.

I installed the Guest Additions, and added a shared folder:

[image]

[image]

After rebooting Kubuntu, I can see the shared folder in Dolphin, but can't access it:

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was a permission issue:

[image]

The solution is to add the current user to the `vboxsf` group:

```
sudo usermod -aG vboxsf $(whoami)
```

Comment: Also you may need to restart.
VirtualBox manual notes are [here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sf_mount_auto)

Comment: @Svilen, confirmed, I had to restart before it worked. Also, as of May 2022 this still worked.